# What is an "Obfuscation key" in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, database-internals

Jokes aside, what is an "Obfuscation key"? I'm just going [off the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/system-base-tables).

> `sys.sysclsobjs` Exists in every database. Contains a row for each classified entity that shares the same common properties that include the following:
>
> ...
>
> Obfuscation key.

This seems to involve

- `Content/binn/sqllang.dll`
- `Content/binn/sqlmin.dll`

I would like to know what the key does and what is being obfuscated, and if that's available for the user.

Answer (score 7):

I would guess they mean rows created for symmetric keys.

```
create symmetric key KeyTest with 
  algorithm = aes_128, 
  identity_value = '123456'
  encryption by password = '123456!Q';

go

-- Needs a DAC connection    
select *
from sys.sysclsobjs
where Name = 'KeyTest'
```

Result:

```
class id    name      status  type intprop  created                 modified
----- ----- --------- ------- ---- -------- ----------------------- -----------------------
56    259   KeyTest   0       A1   128      2017-12-22 08:43:33.170 2017-12-22 08:43:33.170
```

Answer (score -4):

I *think* this is the internal infrastructure behind ["Dynamic Data Masking"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/01/25/use-dynamic-data-masking-to-obfuscate-your-sensitive-data/) which seems to be relatively new thing,

> Traditionally, the logic of **obfuscating** sensitive data has been developed in the application layer, requiring it to be duplicated across all modules and applications accessing the data.  [...] SQL Server 2016 and Azure SQL DB now offer a built-in feature that helps limit access to those particular sensitive data fields: Dynamic Data Masking (DDM).

That's the only link to the word "obfuscating" that I see though. To the user interface, this is called "Masking", and it's accessible to users with,

```
ALTER TABLE [SalesLT].[Customer]
ALTER COLUMN [Phone] ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()')
```

After the column is masked, it requires 'UNMASK` privilege,